# Calculate $\int_{\partial S}-ydx+(x-xz)dy+e^xdz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the cylinder $S=\{x^2+y^2=1, 0\leq z \leq 1\}$

I am asked to calculate ${\int_{\partial S}}-ydx+(x-xz)dy+e^xdz$ with the orientation induced by the orientation of $S$

Of course $\partial S$ means the edge of the cylinder, so in this case I have to integrate the integral form $\omega$ on the curves $$\partial S_1=(\cos(u),\sin(u),1)\\\partial S_2=(\cos(u),\sin(u),0)$$

parametrized by $0\leq u \leq 2\pi$.

Computing: $dx=-\sin(u)du, \ dy=\cos(u)\,du,\ dz=0$

Because $$\int_M \omega  = \int_U \varphi^*\omega$$
we have 
$$\int_M \omega=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(u)du+\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(u)+\cos^2(u)\,du=3\pi$$ where the first integral of the LHS belongs to $\partial S_1$ and the last integral to $\partial S_2$.

Is this correct? I did not have the orientation in mind when solving this problem.

Comment: You should have the orientations of the two parts of $\partial S$ in mind, since they are oriented in different directions (when you look at their projections on the $xy$ plane).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain $S$ is the curved part of the surface of a compact cylinder, for which two choices of orientation are possible; we shall choose the orientation $\mathcal O$ pointing "outward", i.e. the one determined by the unit vector field $x/\|x\|$ for all $x \in S$. The border of $S$ is the disconnected set $\partial S = \partial S_1 \cup \partial S_2$, with your notation; the orientation $\mathcal O$ induces the orientation $\partial \mathcal O$ on $\partial S$ such that $\partial S_1$ is traversed in the *clockwise* sense (w.r.t. the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf z}$) while $\partial S_2$ is traversed in the *counterclockwise* sense. Thus, in order to respect the induced orientation $\partial\mathcal O$, you would have to parametrize $\partial S_1$ and $\partial S_2$ accordingly:
$$\begin{split}
\gamma_1(t) &= (\cos (t), \text{–}\sin (t), 1), \quad t \in [0,2\pi] \\
\gamma_2(t) &= (\cos (t), \sin (t), 0), \quad t \in [0,2\pi].
\end{split}$$
Thus,
$$dx|_{\partial S} = \text{–}\sin(t) \mathop{}\!dt, \qquad \begin{cases}
dy|_{\partial S_1} = \text{–}\cos(t) \mathop{}\!dt,\\
dy|_{\partial S_2} = \cos(t) \mathop{}\!dt,
\end{cases} \qquad dz|_{\partial S} = 0.$$
Setting $\omega = \text{–}y \mathop{}\!dx + x(1-z)\mathop\!dy + e^x\mathop{}\!dz $, the integral can be calculated as
$$\int_{\partial S} \omega = \int_{\partial S_1} \omega + \int_{\partial S_2} \omega = \int_0^{2\pi} (\text{–}\sin^2(t)\mathop{}\!{dt}) + \int_0^{2\pi} (\sin^2(t)\mathop{}\!dt +\cos^2(t)\mathop{dt}) = \text{–}\pi + 2\pi = \boxed \pi.$$
As you can see, the only difference from your answer is that the first integral in the last equation has a negative sign, ultimately because
$$\int_{-M} \omega = - \int_{M} \omega$$
where $M$ indicates a suitable oriented manifold and $-M$ the same manifold endowed with the opposite orientation.